# Subsets in R studio (basic questions)?

Tags: r, subset, mean

I am terrible with R and I am trying to figure out subsets. I have entered the data file into R studio via:

```
> Vehicle_Data <-read.table("VehicleData.txt.txt", header=T,sep="\t",quote="")
> attach(Vehicle_Data)
```

I'm confused about subsets. One of the columns in my data is `Type` which includes a variety of vehicle types. I need to narrow down `Car` within the type column so I can calculate the mean `MPG` value of the cars only.
Here's what I have tried:

```
> TypeCar<-subset(Vehicle_Data, Type=="Car")
```

I think this worked to subset the data, but I'm not sure. Also I have no idea how to calculate the `mean` `MPG` from the subset?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be good if you can include some sample data (using `dput`). You could simply use `mean(TypeCar$MPG)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for subsetting appears to be fine. To calculate the mean, you need to use the `mean()` function in this way:

```
mean_mpg <- mean(TypeCar$MPG, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This code will also take care of any NA values present in your data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyverse` perform data transformations such as subsetting (filtering)

```
Vehicle_Data %>% 
  filter(Type=="Car")
```

You can also calculate the mean `MPG` per Type  like so:

```
Vehicle_Data %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(mean.MPG=mean(MPG, na.rm = TRUE))
```

If you'd like to calculate the mean of an existing subset of data (i.e. `TypeCar`), you can just run `mean(TypeCar$MPG, na.rm = TRUE)`